# drop down submenu in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

hope my question is clear

On pressing on the unique button i have on this page, i want to display the menu having three elements only.

the "Languages" item menu wraps a submenu that  i want to display only if the user clicks on "Languages"

however for the moment whenever i click  on the button, not only the menu appears but also the submenu; and that is not what i want to have.

can you please inform me what is wrong with my code please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeEaJ.png)

Code:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("languageslist").classList.toggle("show");

}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdownb {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction2()">Show</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Countries</p>
    <p id="btnl" onclick="myFunction3()">Languages</p>
    <div id="languageslist">
      <a href="">English</a>
      <a href="">Spanish</a>
      <a href="">German</a>
    </div>
    <p>Continents</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added the answer check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not hiding the `submenu` at initial stage.

Add a class to `languagelist` & hide it. On click of it toggle the class

**HTML**

```
<div id = "languageslist" class="hide"> // add a class here
        <a href="">English</a>
        <a href="">Spanish</a>
        <a href="">German</a>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction3() {
    document.getElementById("languageslist").classList.toggle("hide");
    document.getElementById("languageslist").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vyxknpwn/)

Comment: perfect and nice !